# How to send email using mail() function from wamp 3.0.6

Tags: php, email, wamp

How to send email from wamp server version 3.0.6 using SMTP, Can any one give me right solution ? I'm using php mail()   function

Comment: using phpmailer SMTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using phpmailer sending Email from Local Web Server without using mail().

Following below links :

https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer